# 'address already in use', but I don't see where

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I am trying to start a docker container on a specific ip by adding this to the docker-compose file:

```
- ports
  - 'xxx.xxx.253.202:443:443'
```

And I get this:

error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint api_server (7b45d6741b8eeaecae2ff4ed1da217531f79d852a596b8f7a08cd6ee55a8ab9d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 xxx.xxx.253.202:443: bind: address already in use

But when I look at the connections:

```
> ss -atp
State         Recv-Q    Send-Q         Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port         Process
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:postgresql            0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1937,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:https                 0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1377,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:9090                  0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1378,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:5000                  0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1443,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:redis                 0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=813646,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096         xxx.xxx.253.201:http                  0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=661622,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096         xxx.xxx.253.201:ftp                   0.0.0.0:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=661635,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         128                  0.0.0.0:ssh                   0.0.0.0:*             users:(("sshd",pid=1046,fd=3))
ESTAB         0         0             xxx.xxx.102.49:ssh              80.71.49.109:56098         users:(("sshd",pid=802944,fd=4))
ESTAB         0         152           xxx.xxx.102.49:ssh              80.71.49.109:62244         users:(("sshd",pid=809288,fd=4))
CLOSE-WAIT    0         0                 172.18.0.1:42636              172.18.0.8:postgresql    users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1937,fd=14))
FIN-WAIT-2    0         0                  127.0.0.1:postgresql          127.0.0.1:59520         users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1937,fd=13))
CLOSE-WAIT    0         0                  127.0.0.1:59520               127.0.0.1:postgresql    users:(("sshd",pid=802944,fd=10))
CLOSE-WAIT    0         0                 172.18.0.1:48950              172.18.0.8:postgresql    users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1937,fd=22))
FIN-WAIT-2    0         0                  127.0.0.1:postgresql          127.0.0.1:56550         users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1937,fd=21))
CLOSE-WAIT    0         0                  127.0.0.1:56550               127.0.0.1:postgresql    users:(("sshd",pid=802944,fd=11))
ESTAB         0         0             xxx.xxx.102.49:ssh              80.71.49.109:64028         users:(("sshd",pid=819293,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                    [::]:postgresql               [::]:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1960,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                    [::]:https                    [::]:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1392,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                    [::]:9090                     [::]:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1391,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                    [::]:5000                     [::]:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1450,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         4096                    [::]:redis                    [::]:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=813653,fd=4))
LISTEN        0         128                     [::]:ssh                      [::]:*             users:(("sshd",pid=1046,fd=4))
```

I don't see anything using the .202 address.

The network addresses are as follows:

```
> ip address show
eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:2f:37:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet xxx.xxx.102.49/26 brd xxx.xxx.102.63 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.201/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global eno1:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.202/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global secondary eno1:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.203/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global secondary eno1:3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.204/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global secondary eno1:4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.205/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global secondary eno1:5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.253.206/29 brd xxx.xxx.253.207 scope global secondary eno1:6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::52eb:f6ff:fe2f:3751/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: `LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:https                 0.0.0.0:*` A process is listening on the HTTPS port on all IPv4 addresses. And on all IPv6 addresses `... [::]:https ...`

Comment: ahhh yes, I missed that! it looks like the docker daemon itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line which listen on port 443:

```
LISTEN        0         4096                 0.0.0.0:https                 0.0.0.0:*
```

And next time add `n` to the command line to see the numbers, not resolved protocols.

```
ss -antp
```

P.S. `0.0.0.0` mean any IP on the machine.